# angular 4 *ngFor extra cycles unnecessary?

Tags: angular, ngfor

What is wrong with this plunker, the counting begins at 5?

http://plnkr.co/edit/n0qIlzG8TN1GXjtoFA8y?p=preview

```
   <div *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
       <p>{{inc()}} - {{joke}}</p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because how change detection works in angular. First of all when in development every change detection is running twice.

To change this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode()
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Then to make your code work as expected change changedetectionstrategy to OnPush

```
@Component({
selector: 'joke-list',
template: `
<div *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
<p>{{inc()}} - {{joke}}</p>
</div>`,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Plunkr with the solution: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SxjUG1Am38EywvQizL3j?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line:

```
 <p>{{inc()}} - {{joke}}</p>
```

Like so:

```
<p>{{jokes.indexOf(joke)}} - {{joke}}</p>
```

That way you will always get the number of the item in the array, improve readability and even save some lines of code.

Comment: This answer does not explain why is the plunkr not working.

Comment: You should still explain what's wrong with the current code, otherwise what does the dev learn from it?

Comment: He still does not know _why_ is is a proper way rather than "another way"

Comment: it is OK and works, but I would like to know why are so many extra calls to inc() function in the code?

Comment: @ristepan see the **change detection** link in my answer, it describes the situation Angular doing things "under the hood"

Comment: @ristepan yeah, not sure about that, sorry. But you should consider using other methods to keep track of your array indexes like I and R.Richards pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work well, because `{{ inc() }}` in your template is invoked each time a *change detection cycle is triggered*. I.e. it will be invoked more times than there are items in your `jokes` field.

Instead you should rely on the `index` variable provided by Angular (as other respondents suggested).

Here's the link to the official documentation on [ngFor directive](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html).

Also, read about [change detection in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) if you **really** want to know why your original code did not work as you expected.

Comment: Dear down voter, could you explain what is wrong with my answer?